# How to filter data in ui-select directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, filter, multi-select, ui-select

I have to create a directive (wrapper) over ui-select to ease customer.
This dropdown will have 3 sections in its values
1. Teachers
2. Subjects
3. Students

Requirements:

1. Headings are not selectable (should be disabled) so you can only select values under any of the sections from dropdowns. This I can achieve.
2. It should be multi-selectable. User can select either, teacher, student or subject.  This works in Visual Studio.
3. Filtering when user types
4. Load data when user starts to type in the control.

I have created a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/noB1HhFvvwXZerhsAMIE

CODE
index.html

```
  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <div>
        <data-multi-select data-model="selectedData"></data-multi-select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
    (function () {
        var app = angular.module('githubViewer', ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize']);

        var MainController = function ($scope) {
            $scope.selectedData = [];

            $scope.message = "Github Viewer";
        };

        app.controller("MainController", MainController);
    }());


multiSelectControl.js
'use strict';

(function () {
    var app = angular.module("githubViewer");

    app.directive('multiSelect', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'multiSelectTemplate.html',
            scope: {
                ngModel : '=',
            },
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.data = [];

                scope.teachers = [{ Data: "Teacher1", Title: "teacher" }, { Data: "Teacher2", Title: "Teacher" }, { Data: "Teacher3", Title: "Teacher" }];
                scope.subjects = [{ Data: "Subject1", Title: "Subject" }, { Data: "Subject2", Title: "Subject" }, { Data: "Subject3", Title: "Subject" }];
                scope.stidents = [{ Data: "Student1", Title: "Student" }, { Data: "Student2", Title: "Student" }, { Data: "Student3", Title: "Student" }];

                scope.data.push({ Data: "Teachers", Title: "Title"});
                angular.forEach(scope.teachers, function (value, key) {
                    scope.data.push(value);
                });

                scope.data.push({ Data: "Subjects", Title: "Title" });
                angular.forEach(scope.subjects, function (value, key) {
                    scope.data.push(value);
                });

                scope.data.push({ Data: "Students", Title: "Title" });
                angular.forEach(scope.students, function (value, key) {
                    scope.data.push(value);
                });
            }
        };
    });

    app.filter('propsFilter', function () {
        return function (items, props) {
            var out = [];

            if (angular.isArray(items)) {
                items.forEach(function (item) {
                    var itemMatches = false;

                    var keys = Object.keys(props);
                    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                        var prop = keys[i];
                        var text = props[prop].toLowerCase();
                        if (item[prop].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
                            itemMatches = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (itemMatches) {
                        out.push(item);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Let the output be the input untouched
                out = items;
            }

            return out;
        };
    });
})();
```

multiSelectTemplate.html

```
<ui-select theme='bootstrap' multiple ng-model="selectedData" style="width: 800px;" ng-disabled="disabled">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Organisation, team, component">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Data as item in data track by $index | propsFilter: {Data: $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.Data | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I am not plunk so drop down does not appear but when I run in VS, drop down is working fine. I can do multiselect.

Help:

1. I am trying to filter when user types, e.g. teacher name or student name. so if some one types "Aba", then dropdown should only have values with "aba" in the Data, column.
2. How can I load data in dropdown when user starts to type. so dropdown should be blank, when someone starts typing, dropdown should get loaded.